# Compiling c# code in visual studio code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

First off, I'm not sure if this is the correct spot for this problem, but I am on windows. I am trying to compile c# code on windows 7 using visual studio code. I have all the extensions downloaded but am getting this error:

> launch: program 'launch: launch.json must be configured. Change 'program' to the path to the executable file that you would like to debug.

I can not figure out how to fix it.  This is the line which I believe needs to be changed in the launch.json file, this is what is currently there:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<exam1.dll>",
```

(exam1 because that is the name of my .cs file containing my csharp code).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: borderline on-topic here. Maybe you'll get better answer at stackoverflow.com, that is the site for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `exam1` is the name of the *directory* where your project is (that's what decides the name of the executable, not the name of the C# file), and that you didn't modify your project.json (so it's targeting .Net Core 1.0), then the line should be:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/exam1.dll",
```

If this does not work for you, you can find out what is the right path by building your project (`dotnet build` on the command line or running the build task from the <kbd>F1</kbd> menu) and then looking into the `bin/Debug` subdirectory.

Comment: when I go into the folder where my .cs file is, this is the whole path: "C:\Users\Kdrumz\Desktop\ObjectOriented\exam 1.cs". I am so confused, I tried clicking f1, but it brought up the same launch.json error. Any ideas?